# View the names of clustered objects

Tags: r, k-means, dbscan

I have a sample of cities of data and I am Clustering them for some parameters. But I'm having trouble representing them visually, first used the clusplot, but I can not understand why the scales change, since even plotting with only 2 components and data ranging from -1 to 1, have ranges from -4 to 4 and -2 to 2, as you can see in the example [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAVVd.png).

[[image: clusplot[1]]

So I use the hullplot DBSCAN package, but that plot does not show in your output the name of the cities, as clusplot, see [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Yd3P.png). Could someone give me a suggestion of how to add these names to the chart?

[image: hullplot]

Comment: please add the code which creates the plots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to use ggplot2 and ggrepel packages for this. I borrowed code to make the convex hull from [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22805/how-to-draw-neat-polygons-around-scatterplot-regions-in-ggplot2).

```
set.seed(175)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel) # Or first install.packages("ggrepel")

# Make the cluster
mtcars$cluster <- as.factor(kmeans(mtcars, 3)$cluster)

# Get the convex hull for the axes you want to plot
hull_df <- plyr::ddply(mtcars, "cluster", function(dta) {
    hull <- chull(dta$mpg, dta$disp)
    dta[c(hull, hull[1]), ]
})

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, color = cluster, fill = cluster)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_polygon(data = hull_df, alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = row.names(mtcars)))
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me a lot!
If you know any reference to explain how clusplot works, I would be very grateful, because for what I sought, he is the only one who can plot clustering with more than two parameters, or it uses only the 2 most significant parameters, running something like a selection of variables? PCA ?!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples how to do this with dbscan:

```
library(dbscan)
set.seed(2)
n <- 400

x <- cbind(
  x = runif(4, 0, 1) + rnorm(n, sd=0.1),
  y = runif(4, 0, 1) + rnorm(n, sd=0.1),
  z = runif(4, 0, 1) + rnorm(n, sd=0.1)
)
cl <- rep(1:4, time = 100)

### show some points (first 10) inside the hulls with text
hullplot(x, cl, main = "True clusters", pch = NA)
points(x[1:10,])
text(x[1:10,], labels = paste("Obs.", 1:10), pos = 3)

### look at dimensions x and z 
hullplot(x[, c("x", "z")], cl, main = "True clusters")

### use a PCA projection
hullplot(prcomp(x)$x, cl, main = "True clusters")
```

You can look at package wordcloud for better word layout. See [here.](http://blog.fellstat.com/?cat=11)